# Exports reference and exports pointer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am having problem with exporting my routing table in my express application.

First in /bin/www.js file I got my global variable which reporesents routing table:

```
var routingTable = [];
```

Then to create a simple routing I am just pushing new routing objects using server listening event.

```
server.on('listening', onListening);

function onListening() {
     var addr = server.address();
     var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
     ? 'pipe ' + addr
     : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
  routingTable.push({
     address: "localhost:8080",
     version: 1,
     name: "some-service"
  });
}
```

When i console.log routingTable after push i got this single object in it.

Then I created a getter for that variable:

```
exports.getRouting = function() {
   return routingTable;
};
```

This getter is exported to routes file:

```
var getRoutingTable = require('../bin/www').getRouting;
```

After I use this getRoutingTable function i got an empty array. What is the right way to export this variable so it can be use and updated in every other project file?

Comment: I think server listening event is not working.That's why `routingTable` remains blank.

Comment: @LalitGoswami please read description once again. When I console.log in onListening() function it shows table with element added.

Answer (score 0):

Is routingTable define in '../bin/www'?

```
var routingTable = [];
...
exports.getRouting = function() {
    return routingTable;
};
```

Comment: Variable and export function are from the same file.

Comment: What result of console.log(require('../bin/www').getRouting()) ? Perhaps: on application is start routingTable is empty, when you call "require(...)" it in other place is empty too and finally routing table is not empty when server started listening. Try to add timer and call getRouting() again.

Comment: The result is the single object pushed in onListening() function. I personally think that timer is a straight bad solution. Also require is done on **getRouting** not on a variable itself.